# Animate the closest div

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an image and a div. If I hover on the image the div comes into visible. 
I want to use the same effect to another image and div. But if I hover any image both the divs are showing. How can I animate individually? Here is the code I am using

```
$(".home_plus_1 img").hover(function () {
    $(".hp_1_cont").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
}, function () {
    $(".hp_1_cont").animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
});




<div class="home_plus_1 plus_holder"> 
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/plus.png" alt="">
  <div class="hp_1_cont">
    <div class="hp1_t">Jeden Montag, 
      Mittwoch, Samstag &
      Sonntag FKK Tage Bei uns im Club</div>
    <div class="hp_1_conb">An allen anderen Tagen treffen Sie in unseren Clubräumlichekeiten die heißen Girls in sexy Dessous an!</div>
  </div>

  <!-- hp_1_cont --> 
</div>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help with this if we could see the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any HTML structure, I'd say something like this should help:

```
$(".home_plus_1 img").hover(function () {
    $(this).next().animate({opacity: "1"}, {queue: false});
}, function () {
    $(this).next().animate({opacity: "0"}, {queue: false});
});
```

Edit: Have updated the code to fit the updated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can reach element with `$(this).next()` or `$(this).parent().find('.hp_1_cont')` context. dont search the element on all document

```
$(".home_plus_1 img").hover(function () {
    $(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).next().stop().fadeOut();
});
```